# Snow Leopard - resolving hostnames issue

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard

This worked in Leopard, although since Snowie came along …

I have a Location setup with a DNS server to use [eg 10.0.0.17] , and a search string [eg sub.dom.ain.com]

In the terminal: 
 

`$ nslookup cake 

Server 10.0.0.17 

Address: 10.0.0.17#53 



Name: cake.sub.dom.ain.com 

Address: 10.0.0.38`

So works like a charm. Although if I just the hostname `cake` in any other application within OSX - such as Safari/CoRD, they simply can't resolve the hostname. I have to instead use the FQDN `cake.sub.dom.ain.com` - why is this so? Why did this work in Leopard and is now broken?

Would love a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Justin [was](https://superuser.com/questions/68446/snow-leopard-resolving-hostnames-issue/75390#75390) onto the right idea here, but didn't carry it to the finish line:

In Advanced » DNS, add your `sub.dom.ain.com` to the Search Domains, and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant, but I had a problem when I upgraded where having a custom DNS server in my network settings prevented it from using the DNS servers specified in DHCP from my ISP.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked my DNS settings, I noticed that under `Advanced` there is a `Search Domains` area, which appears to be blank by default.